# Can't present UIView where I want it to be

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I'm trying to show paddle on center of the screen. I dragged a newView into the storyboard, and manually added the paddle UIView on the newView.
However, it is on the right side of the screen, not center. Anyone please let me know why.

```
    var frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 30))
    frame.origin.x = newView.frame.width / 2
    var paddle = UIView(frame: frame)


    paddle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    newView.addSubview(paddle)

    println(newView.center.x)
```

Comment: instead of giving origin CGRectZero take newView frame and calculate center point of that NewView then assign frame to paddle

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use your paddle view width for x

```
 frame.origin.x = (newView.frame.width / 2) -  (frame.width/2)
```

You forgot to use your paddle view height for y

```
 frame.origin.y = (newView.frame.height / 2) -  (frame.height/2)
```